# Install to HP Elitebook 850 has flipped screen. How to correct?

Tags: system-installation, 19.04

I have tried to install Ubuntu 19.04 to my HP 850 Elitebook.

When I boot to the USB, the screen / display is upside down.  What is the best way to resolve?

Comment: what desktop environment are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Use this command

`sudo apt-get remove iio-sensor-proxy`

**OR**

Use the icon that is available in the top right corner of the screen, when you click on the down arrow. The icon is the one in red in the screenshot below:

[image: .]

Comment: Thank you for the response.  The command works but does not save.  The icon is not available in 19.04 for my installation.  Not sure why.